# How to set treeview checkbox with name attribute in kendo template?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview, kendo-mvvm

I'm new to kendo ui and I would like to know how to add name attribute into my kendo treeview by using kendo template?

```
<div id="overviewCheckbox" data-role="treeview" data-text-field="text" data-checkboxes='{"checkChildren": true}' data-value-field="value"
     data-bind="visible:isVisibleTree,events:{check:onChecked}" style="overflow:hidden"></div>
<div id="overviewGrid" data-bind="visible:isVisiblegrid">
```

my kendo template

```
  # if(!item.hasChildren){#<input type='hidden' parent_id='#=item.value#' d_text='#=item.value#' /><input type='checkbox' name='checkedFiles[#= item.value #]' value='true' />#}else{#<input type='checkbox' parent_id='#=item.parent_id#' name='checkedFiles[#= item.value #]' /> #}#
```

if i use the template then it will give an output like this:

```
[ ][ ]
   [ ][ ]
   [ ][ ]
   [ ][ ]
```

expected output of my treeview

```
[ ]Animal
   [ ]Dog
   [ ]Cat
   [ ]Fish
```

Answer (score 0):

You're telling the widget to generate its own checkboxes. As you want to add attributes to your checkbox, you have to use [`checkbox.template`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treeview#configuration-checkboxes.template) to tell the widget to render a custom checkbox, and remove the checkbox from the value template. On the value template, you may keep your `hidden` field, but you have to display the node's text, e.g. `#= item.text #` somewhere.